# GoogleSheet : Crossing data from two tables

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using GoogleSheet, I have two tables as input:

First table:

| Name | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe |  | X | X | X |
| Jess | X | X |  | X |
| Mark |  | X |  | X |

meaning that **Joe** has val1 . val3 . val4, **Jess** has val1 . val2 . val4, **Mark** has val2 . val4

Second table is like a matrix:

| val1  |  val2  |  val3  |  val4  
 val1           warn A  warn B
 val2           errA
 val3
 val4

identifying some couples of values associated with some text: **val1.val3**:warn A, **val1.val4**:warn B, **val2.val3**:err A

As result, I would like to join these two tables for extracting a table like this:

Name  | Result     
Joe    warn B (val1.val4), warn A (val1.val3)
Jess   warn A (val1.val4)
Mark

I need to address it using googlesheet but I fail, I have too many steps of transformation and finally I'm lost.

Currently, I though that using binary or operator could help. I proceed like this:

#1 Transform second table **table2** in new dec values from base2 :
   | val1  |  val2  |  val3  |  val4  
 val1 
         10   9
 val2            6
 val3
 val4

1. Each bit corresponds to Val[bit position]. ex : val1 => 1000 , val2 => 0100
2. (Val1, Val4) => BITOR(1000,0001) = 9

#2 same kind of transformation for the first table **table1**:

Name | val1(8) | val2(4) | val3(2) | val4(1)|
Joe    8         2     1
Jess   8    4          1
Mark        4          1

#3 extract relevant values form **table2**
=filter(transpose(flatten(table2)),transpose(flatten(table2))<>0)
I obtain : 10 | 9 | 6 (from table2)

#4 I sum rows in **table1**:

| Name | sum |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | 11 |
| Jess | 13 |
| Mark | 5 |

#5 I apply BITAND operator IF(BITAND(term2,term1)=term1,"Warn") between each terms from terms1 11 | 13 |5 and terms2 : 10 | 9 | 6

for Joe:

```
So as BITAND(11,10)=10 then i got a "Warn" for 1010 => (Val1,Val3)
So as BITAND(11,9)=9 then i got a "Warn" for 1001 => (Val1,Val4)
So as BITAND(11,6) not = 6 then nothing
```

But I implemented this for a small set of data as example and nothing is dynamic regarding the number of columns and rows... I guess if there a kind of function or query which could replace in a good way my poor code.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: the example of desired output is wrong I believe. pls check it

Comment: Thanks both for your comments, I did updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A2:A5, REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B2:E5="X", B1:E1, )),,9^9))), TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FLATTEN(
 IF(B12:E16="",,A12:A16&".*"&B11:E11)), 
 "where Col1 is not null"))), TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FLATTEN(
 IF(B12:E16="",,B12:E16&" ("&A12:A16&"."&B11:E11&"),")), 
 "where Col1 is not null")), )),,9^9))), ",$", )})
```

[image]